# Rollup Windows on Mac

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there anyway to make windows rollup on Mac 10.6? I prefer rollup in some circumstances to minimising because it allows me to easy bring the window back up again.

Comment: what's a rollup? Sorry, English ain't my mother language and yahoo's translation doesn't get me any further...

Comment: install Mac OS 9 :) and @ Damien: Rolling up windows was was a Mac feature which has been removed from OS X. it now available for Windows, basically roll up minimizes a window to the title bar.

Comment: Unsanity's compatibility page shows that WindowShadeX is indeed compatible with Mac OS X 10.6. http://www.unsanity.com/products/compatibility

Comment: They seem to have updated it recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [WindowShade X](https://www.unsanity.com/haxies/wsx).

Comment: It works, but costs $15 :-(

Comment: Link is dead; creator appears to be defunct: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=24502203

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a way to "roll-up" your windows on the Mac. It was called "WindowShade" and it was both officially and unofficially available on the Classic Mac. Apple brought it in as part of Mac OS 8, but it had been available as a third party extension before that.

Now, under Mac OS X, it's no longer officially available. Up to 10.5, a company called unsanity had a "haxie" that would enable this feature: https://www.unsanity.com/haxies/wsx However, that hack isn't available under 10.6.

The option that Apple provides is of course to minimize to the dock, which isn't really a direct replacement for WindowShade, although it has been improved in 10.6.

Comment: It does work on 10.5.x actually, not sure about 10.6.x

Comment: Now works in 10.6

Comment: Unsanity is now apparently dead (and unsanity.com doesn't respond): http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=24502203

Answer (score 1):

Neomobili's Deskovery also features "windowshading", "minimizing to titlebar" or however you'd like to call this feature. Successfully tried and tested on OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score -2):

It's there, just off by default.  Go to:  System Preferences → Appearance → “Double-click a window's title bar to minimize”

Comment: That's minimizing, that's not what the poster wants.